# Confirmed, recovered, deaths, meaning

Tags: covid-19, terminology, epidemiology

I am wondering about the exact definition of a few terms that are being used in connection with the COVID-19, specifically in data sets.

I am interested in the data at [github](https://github.com/datasets/covid-19) specifically in [the time series data](https://github.com/datasets/covid-19/blob/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv) but most likely my question is more universal:

The data contains three columns, titled *Confirmed*, *Recovered*, *Deaths*. Other terminology commonly used include *Total cases*, *Daily New Cases*, *Active Cases*, *Total Deaths*, *Daily Deaths*, ...

Is my understanding of the meaning of these terms correct?

- *Confirmed*, total number of people tested positively until that date (cumulative);
- *Recovered*, total number of people tested positively who are not positive anymore (cumulative). ***Does this include people who died of Corona?***
- *Deaths*, total number of people who died of/with Corona virus (cumulative)
- *Total cases*: same as *Confirmed*?
- *Daily New Cases*(day) = Confirmed(day) - Confirmed(day-1)
- *New Infections*: same as DailyNewCases?
- *DailyRecovered*(day) = Recovered(day) - Recovered(day-1)
- *Total Deaths*: same as *Deaths*?
- *Daily Deaths*(day) = Deaths(day) - Deaths(day-1)
- *ActiveCases*(day) = ActiveCases(day-1) + DailyNewCases(day) - DailyRecovered(day) **OR**  *ActiveCases*(day) = ActiveCases(day-1) + DailyNewCases(day) - DailyRecovered(day) - DailyDeaths(day)

Comment: Recovered data is very incomplete, definitions for confirmed and total cases vary by location. You need a lot more information that just a description of the columns to work with these data. If the data source you are using doesn't come with those details, it's pretty much worthless.

Comment: @BryanKrause I understand that the data is not ideal. Basically I just want to practice a bit of data processing for myself, so it  does not matter all that much. Still would like to get it right as much as possible.

Comment: @BryanKrause If it cannot be said for this particular data source, how about in general? I've seen "recovered" being used to include deaths when talking about mathematical models, the reasoning being that dead people cannot infect other people anymore. In the context of actual data sets however I would expect "recovered" to be only living people. Am I wrong?